# Array / Loop - How to stop iterating if result is true?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

To shape my understandings of arrays I try to understand how to loop through an array.

In an example, I want to check whether a change in time is true and if so, stop iterating.

```
// Define static intervals
INTERVALS = array.from('12M', '3M', '1M', '1W', '1D')

// Read static intervals and check whether its a new instance or not
var newInterval = bool(na)
for [i, interval] in INTERVALS
    newInterval := time(interval) != time(interval)[1]
```

All I try to achieve is to check if a new Year, Quarter, Month, ... has started.

So on a new Year it should return true for the Year only (which is the higher timeframe) and not return true for the start of a new Quarter or new Month (which technically also is true).

On a start of new week for instance, it should return true for the week - even though its a new day as well.

How can I do this?

I know I could use another way to figure this out (e.g. switch or simply write out logic), but the purpose here for me is to learn working better with arrays.

Comment: Note that asking for "the best way" to do something is not allowed on Stack Overflow; such questions are opinion-based and thus off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You picked a hard one, this isn't so easy to archive. And while we do this for education reasons I will recommend using the new `log.()` feature too. I also tried to keep your original structure as far as possible.

One way to solve this is for checking YOUR timeframe for changes only...

```
INTERVALS = array.from('12M', '3M', 'M', 'W', 'D') // had to adjust entries
newInterval = bool(false)
log.warning("Check...")
for [i, interval] in INTERVALS
    if interval == timeframe.period
        newInterval := time(interval) != time(interval)[1] 
        log.info(str.tostring(newInterval))
        break      // stop repeating (iterate)
```

In this case you have to be on one of those timeframes you put into that array, otherwise it will not work. An alternative would be using `timeframe.change(interval)` instead. But I think both of this isn't what you wanted.

BTW, not sure if you notice, but the `newInterval` boolean doesn't need to be declared as `var` it will reinitialize on every tick, unless you want to do some else with it.

**Second approach...**

To archive this I had to add a 2nd array and a new variable called `INTERVALS2` and `new_time`.

```
var INTERVALS  = array.from('12M', '3M', '1M', '1W', '1D')
var INTERVALS2 = array.new<int>(INTERVALS.size(), 0)
newInterval = bool(false)
log.warning("Check...")
for [i, interval] in INTERVALS
    int new_time = time(interval)
    if INTERVALS2.get(i) != new_time
        newInterval := true
        INTERVALS2.set(i, new_time)
    log.info(str.format("{0}: {1}", interval, newInterval))
```

This will work on any timeframe and it won't output endless `true` values, like in your example. The declaration of `INTERVALS2` has the same size as `INTERVALS`, and indexing is also the same. The big difference is the value which is holding the associated UNIX-time. The `new_time` is a simple way for comparison.

While we are at it, I recommend learning the new `map` structure for this too.

```
var INTERVALS = map.new<string, int>()
newInterval = bool(false)

if barstate.isfirst
    INTERVALS.put("12M", time("12M"))
    INTERVALS.put("3M" , time("3M"))
    INTERVALS.put("1M" , time("1M"))
    INTERVALS.put("1W" , time("1W"))
    INTERVALS.put("1D" , time("1D"))

log.warning("Check...")
for [key, value] in INTERVALS
    int value_new = time(key)
    if value != value_new
        newInterval := true
        INTERVALS.put(key, value_new)
    log.info(str.format("{0}: {1}", key, newInterval))
```

This seems to be the same as my second approach, but when things get more complicated then this can save a lot of headache. Instead of an index it uses key and value pairs. In this case `string + int` (key is a string and value is a integer). you create new entries via `*.put()`. when a key already exist it wont create a new one, instead it will overwrite the value only. to get a value you could use `*.get()` which will use the key instead of an index.

Comment: I feel a bit like an a** for not answering earlier after seeing the efforts you put into your response. I simply drowned in family, work, side projects. My apologies.

First of all: Thanks a lot for wrapping your brain around this & looking at it. I now understand why I didn't even got close (and even didn't know about logging being available - awesome!).

Now, the map() function finally makes sense with this example. Very clean. Thanks so much. Gotta dig a bit into it over the weekend but from what I saw in the log window, its what I need to get my hands dirty now. :)

Comment: @iamdifferent no problemo, glad I could help. If you have any other questions you know what to do.

Comment: You respponse is a gold mine of fresh knowledge and should be flagged as educational material. It took me nearly an hour to really understand the difference and impact of what you shared. 

However, I was not precise in my question to really solve what bugs me for several weeks now.

I am about to create a new follow up question to avoid polluting the goldmine of a response you already shared. 

Thanks again. This already changed A LOT for me.