# How to convert the following function to array in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I would like know how to convert the following function to array in Pinescript.
This is to convert resolution to appear as string.
I was trying "array.from(x, y, z)", but didn't succeeded.

Will there be speed improvements?

Code:

```
res_to_str(_res) =>
    if _res == ''
        ''
    else if _res == '1'
        '1m'
    else if _res == '3'
        '3m'
    else if _res == '5'
        '5m'
    else if _res == '15'
        '15m'
    else if _res == '30'
        '30m'
    else if _res == '45'
        '45m'
    else if _res == '60'
        '1h'
    else if _res == '120'
        '2h'
    else if _res == '180'
        '3h'
    else if _res == '240'
        '4h'
    else if _res == '1D'
        'D'
    else if _res == '1W'
        'W'
    else if _res == '1M'
        'M'
    else if _res == '3M'
        '3M'
    else if _res == '6M'
        '6M'
    else if _res == '12M'
        '12M'
    else
        _res
```

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: For this I recommend using [Maps](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Maps.html) instead. An example you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77166970/7644275) at the bottom.

Comment: @vitruvius eg: '4h' text as label when in '240' tf.